# What speaker sizes are in a 1991 VW Polo coupe?

Tags: audio

Title says it all, what are the speaker sizes in a volkswagen golf coupe from 1991?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After measuring the speakerbays I bought some cheap speakers in standard size closest to my measurements, which fit perfectly. 
The front (dash) speakers are 3-1/2" diameter, the rear (trunk) speakers are 6"x4". I hope this helps someone else one day!

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find any good documentation online for the speaker sizes of a VW Polo.  Your best bet is to do it the old fashioned way - take out the speakers and measure them.  If you're going to replace the speakers then you have to take them out eventually anyways. There is a good article on eHow for [measuring car speakers](http://www.ehow.com/how_4883570_measure-car-speakers-replacement.html) for replacement.

Comment: There are currently no speakers in the car. However going by standards I think I have pinpointed the actual sizes. I'll report back here once I've fitted new speakers and know for sure.

Comment: If there are no speakers won't you have to cut the holes anyway?  So pick what fit's best.

Comment: There were precut holes were once the speakers were. I measured those and bought me some cheap speakers in a standard size which was the closest to my measurements. I'll post my findings in a new answer, so maybe one day it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://www.pioneer.eu/uk/products/car_accessories/VW/Polo_3-door_and_Coup%C3%A9/10_1990/index.html